# how to decode an ASCII code back to string in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ascii

I Have a problem with decoding ASCII code back to string.

First I take a text input from user and convert it to ASCII code which is consecutively assigned to a label. Than I want to convert it from that label  back to the normal string. But in stead of the string I receive a random symbols.

I believe it's because the function can't distinguish when a code for a certain letter starts and when it's finishes. Any Idea how can i set a delimiter or something like that? if ever it's going to solve the problem of course

this is the code i used:

```
 Protected Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Label3.Text = ""
    For x As Integer = 1 To TextBox3.Text.Length
        Label3.Text &= CStr(Asc(Mid$(TextBox3.Text, x, 1)))
    Next
End Sub

Protected Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Label4.Text = ""
    For x As Integer = 1 To Label3.Text.Length
        Label4.Text &= Chr(Mid$(Label3.Text, x, 1))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: When you convert the ASCII codes back to characters, you are always taking 1 character at a time when some of the ASCII codes could be 2 or 3 characters long. There is no way to tell without a delimiter between them how many characters to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Label3.Text = ""
  For x As Integer = 1 To TextBox3.Text.Length
    Label3.Text &= CStr(Asc(Mid$(TextBox3.Text, x, 1))) & "|"
  Next
End Sub


Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
  Label4.Text = ""
  Dim value As Integer = 0
  Dim buf As String = ""
  For x As Integer = 1 To Label3.Text.Length
    If Mid$(Label3.Text, x, 1) <> "|" Then
      buf &= Mid$(Label3.Text, x, 1)
    Else
      Label4.Text &= Chr(Val(buf))
      buf = ""
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```